# R - draw a cylinder around dataset

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am plotting a dataset using `scatterplot3d` and I need to draw a cylinder containing it. What is the easiest way to do that?

An example dataset can be downloaded from [here](https://gist.github.com/albusdemens/3536669723c95a6f3a7d30a76ff06a72). The cylinder should be centred in (100,100) and have radius 100.

This is the code I am using to plot the points:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
require(plot3D)
library(rgl)
require(gridExtra)
library(scatterplot3d)

Data = read.table("data.txt")
X = as.numeric(unlist(Data[1]))
Y = as.numeric(unlist(Data[2]))
Z = as.numeric(unlist(Data[3]))

# 3D plot
scatterplot3d(X, Y, Z, pch = 16)
```

Comment: Do you already know how to find the "containing" cylinder? What information do you have to do the drawing? It would help if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with some data to plot and, if possible, a sketch of the desired result

Comment: @MrFlick I included all the info in the question text. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: `scatterplot3d` uses base graphics. I'm not aware that there are handy functions for drawing cylinders isn that plotting paradigm. Also `ggplot2` is famous for its lack of support of 3d graphics. I think you should move your development efforts to `rgl`. (You have loaded packages doing graphics in at least 3 different plotting paradigms, so the end destination of this effort is very unclear.)